# Как получить ID рубрики зная ее название?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот так выглядит в админке объявление рубрики в кастомном типе постов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зная название "Дома 5" нужно получить ID рубрики. Как это сделать?

Comment: [Было решено в этом топе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536682/get-wordpress-post-id-from-post-title). (Ещё символы для публикации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать функцию get_term_by() для того что бы получить таксономию и уже из нее использовать id, подробнее по ссылке https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/

Это будет выглядеть примерно вот так

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', 'Дома 5, 'category' );
echo $term->term_id;
```